# decibel to linear conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, audio

I'm working on a NodeJS module to control my amplifier from various sources.

The amplifier can only be set to a specific "decibel" from -60dB to +10dB.
However, this is totally not linear. -60 to -50 (10dB increase) cannot be heard, while 0dB to 10+dB is the difference between "ok" and blowing out the speakers.

I've found that decibel (dB) is a logarithmic unit. And this is especially noticeable when using a slider to control the volume.
And I've found some [mathematical](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38722/convert-db-value-to-linear-scale) solutions.

But I do not know how this would translate into code (specifically NodeJS/Javascript).

Comment: I don't know who told you that rubbish. But the usage of dB is largely due to the psychoacoustics that mean that hearing is largely non-linear, and much more closely modelled as logarithmic.

Answer (score 2):

For voltage signal level and sound power formula is

dB = 20 * Log10 (CurrentLevel / NormalLevel)
so
CurrentLevel =  NormalLevel * 10<sup>dB / 20</sup>

Pseudocode is straightforward:

```
 CurrentLevel =  NormalLevel * Math.Power(10.0, dB / 20.0)
```